# I want to change the display of SnippetChooserPanel of BlogIndexPage by Client in Wagtail site

Tags: django, wagtail

I want to change the display of SnippetChooserPanel of BlogIndexPage by Client.
However, I don't have an idea to change the display.

I want to display only the contract of the same client.
But now all contracts are visible.

What I investigated：

[Filter query set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57552920/how-can-i-return-a-queryset-for-a-fk-or-m2m-field-in-wagtail-admin-create-form)

[wagtail-ModelAdmin.get_queryset()](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.6.1/reference/contrib/modeladmin/indexview.html#modeladmin-get-queryset)

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super().get_queryset(request)
    return qs.filter(client=request.client)
```

Comment: A look here (https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/hooks.html?highlight=hooks#choosers) makes it seem like what you want to do isn't currently possible within Wagtail.  Hopefully at some point there will be a `construct_snippet_chooser_queryset` hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here the solution that worked for me:

```py
class CustomizedChooserPanel(SnippetChooserPanel):
    def on_form_bound(self) -> None:
        self.form.fields["your_field_name"].queryset = self.model.objects.filter(client=request.client)
        super().on_form_bound()
```

then in your content_panels:

```py
content_panels = (
        [CustomizedChooserPanel("your_field_name")]
    )
```